# Using GitHub pages and ability for users to log in and contribute

Tags: github-pages

I am trying to get my head around whether github pages is a fit solution for a website I want to build.

I want to build a site where other users can make contributions. 
For example:

Imagine a page where a user can push some text.

```
user: [john-plug]
text: [hello everyone] 
[submit]
```

would it be then possible to retrieve it like this:

http:[staticpage]github.io/messages/john-plug

returns: `hello everyone`

Comment: I have looked at this for all of 15 seconds, but I think it would not be a good solution. It sounds like you want a Wiki. Have you considered using a wiki?

Comment: @mrunion ... My example was to give a gist of what I am after. no I don't want a wiki, but it's fair to say that I am wondering if it would be possible to build "a kinda wiki site" via github pages.